# Android change text in textview on swipe with animation

Tags: android, animation, textview, swipe

I am developing an android application and i have set of messages to show on a display page. At a given time only one message will be shown, but if user swipes the screen i want to change the message on textview on swipe in animated fashion. I want animation direction based on swipe direction meaning if user swipe left to right then left-right textview animation, similarly right-left and bottom-top animation. Please advise me how to achieve this.

Comment: This is something urgent for me. I will appreciate a prompt help.

Comment: Instead of changing the TextView would you consider having the whole screen swipe and then a new textview replace the first? This is what Android design would dictate.

Comment: Nope i don't want that. As page is having a few other icons and etc. which are same for every page. So i just want text in textview to be changed in animated way so that user can feel that text got changed on swipe.

Comment: How about having just the Textview get swiped over and replaced by another TextView. Obviously there are ways to do what you want, but as an Android user I feel like it would be completely out of place in the OS? Also changing the text on a gesture can cause for problems where the user didn't mean to swipe whereas if the textview starts moving, they know to stop...

Comment: If you are set on doing gesture detection, I can help you, but I don't recommend it...

Comment: i want text to be changed if user swipe anywhere on page. As this is message display page. However how to replace textview with another textview on swipe ? Do you mean if i have n message, shall i create n textviews in buffer ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38251/discussion-between-rsenapps-and-user1908860)

Comment: i am open to a best possible solution. And fyi number of messages could be more than 5000 , so need a design to suit it.

Answer (score 2):

After talking, the best solution we found was to use a ViewPager to hold just the textview. This way you get a natural swiping type motion. To implement the random switch, we used gesture recognition and a slide-up animation found here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/